# Need help with choosing a resistor

Tags: resistors

I want to start by saying im really not educated with ohms law and how to figure out this equation that im dealing with. Okay, so currently I have an older 1997 F-150 that i converted the headlight bulbs into Leds with (6 ohm, 50 watt, 2.25 amp draw) load resistor kits. Now i’m trying to put custom tow mirrors on with leds but i’m needing to run 2 wires from the led headlight bulbs (after resistors) back to the mirrors through the doors. The headlights have 2 power wires (turn signal and running light). So i spliced into those two wires with 2 diodes (3 amp - 12v) to run to the (1 wire) led tow mirror light. I’m looking to install another resistor for the running light to the tow mirror led I am just not sure what size resistor because i don’t want the tow mirror led too dim where it is not noticeable. The idea im trying to do is here at this link.

https://youtu.be/EyOcy_WdeNs

[image]

Comment: Does anyone know why the spec for this resistor has "Clicking Sound: No" as the 1st item? I don't recall ever wondering if my resistors made clicking sounds... ;)

Comment: @brhans It's because this is used as a turn signal load. (*"Connect one across each LED turn signal bulb to simulate filament Tail/Turn signal bulbs."*) Some, feeling the heft of it, might imagine it also performs some kind of loud audible clicking action for them as the signal blinks. They're just nipping the idea in the bud, so that if someone complains they can point to the TOP of the sheet where it says it doesn't click. (You cannot find a reasoning level below which you won't find plenty of your customers still at. *"Don't swallow it."* should probably be included.)